# What wire are mechanical keyboard switch compression springs made of?

Tags: springs

What specific wire is used for mechanical keyboard switch compression springs? I am trying to create my own mechanical keyboard switch springs, I have tried stainless steel dental wires but it does not retain the spring shape very well.

Comment: dental wires are not stainless steel ... I ciuld be wrong, but I think that they are memory wire

Comment: @jsotola The heaviest orthodontic wires are stainless steel, but the lighter gauge wires are memory wire.

Answer (score 4):

Spring properties in steel has to do more about heat treatment than the type of steel. It is true that certain types of steel have more potential to make better springs but only with the appropriate heat treatment. If left untreated, they are as good, or as bad, as any other steel.

Use music wire (also goes by the name of piano wire), even though this isn't the actual wire used in pianos. You can buy this at hobby shops for radio controlled trucks and airplanes, among other places. Do not heat it up when trying to bend it or you will destroy the heat treatment.

Most stocks of steel you buy will not be heat treated which means that you would need to do the job yourself which may be beyond your ability. This fact alone puts music wire far ahead of other steels that could potentially make better springs.

Comment: Hobby shop music wire is of uneven quality, and doesn't always make the best springs -- trust me, I've been down that road.  There is wire out there that's made to be wound into springs, and can be obtained either in fully hardened condition (for sane people) or annealed (for crazy talented, or just plain crazy people).  Alas, I don't know where to find it any more.

Comment: @TimWescott McMaster Carr maybe?

Comment: @DKNguyen: Yes, among other places. https://www.mcmaster.com/products/piano-wire/